# CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(tag,type) is deprecated use the save function

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to save captured images and video recording from phone camera to my device gallery, but I get permission denied and error message stating that CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(tag, type) is deprecated. Use the save function instead.

```js
takePicture = async () => {
        if (this.camera) {
            const options = { quality: 1 };
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
            //save photo
            CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri, 'photo').then(onfulfilled => {
                ToastAndroid.show(onfulfilled, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            }).catch(error => {
                ToastAndroid.show(`${error.message}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the new version of CameraRoll the function saveToCameraRoll is being deprecated in favor of the [save](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll#save) function. Only change that you have to do is to change saveToCameraRoll to save like below

```
takePicture = async () => {
        if (this.camera) {
            const options = { quality: 1 };
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
            //save photo
            CameraRoll.save(data.uri, 'photo').then(onfulfilled => {
                ToastAndroid.show(onfulfilled, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            }).catch(error => {
                ToastAndroid.show(`${error.message}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried your code but first before saving we have to ask for permission to write storage

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan i have tried that CameraRoll. save its fine but when i click save button it is showing this error. TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_nativeInterface.default.saveToCameraRoll')

Comment: can you elaborate or show the code of your button ?